# Tic-Tac-Toe class written in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

How well is this Tic Tac Toe code written? Where may I improve it? This is meant to be a platform for a machine learning algorithm.

The code is written so any player may play first. Once a player plays first and starts the game, the code enforces turns. Overwrite protection is also enforced.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
class xo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]];
        self.sym=[' ','0','X'];
        self.turn=0;
        self.modResX=-1;
        self.modResO=-1;
        self.won=False;
        
    def setPos(self,posx,posy,who):
        if (who>=0 & who<3):
            self.board[posx][posy]=who;
        return 0;
        
    def setX(self,posx,posy):
        # check if X is playing first.
        if self.turn==0:
            self.modResX=0;
            self.modResO=1;
        # check if X is not playing out of turn.
        if self.turn%2==self.modResX:
            # check if we are overwriting a position
            if (self.board[posx][posy]==0):
                self.board[posx][posy]=2;
                self.turn+=1;
                self.win(2);
                return 0;
            else:
                return -2;
        else:
            return -1;
    
    def setO(self,posx,posy):
        # check if O is playing first.
        if self.turn==0:
            self.modResX=1;
            self.modResO=0;
        # check if O is not playing out of turn.
        if self.turn%2==self.modResO:
            # check if we are overwriting a position
            if (self.board[posx][posy]==0):
                self.board[posx][posy]=1;
                self.turn+=1;
                self.win(1);
                return 0;
            else:
                return -2;
        else:
            return -1;
    
    def win(self,who):
        win=False;
        if self.board[0]==[who, who, who]:
            win=True;
        if self.board[1]==[who, who, who]:
            win=True;
        if self.board[2]==[who, who, who]:
            win=True;
        if ([self.board[0][0], self.board[1][1], self.board[2][2]]==[who,who,who]):
            win=True;
            
        transList=list(map(list, zip(*self.board)))
        if transList[0]==[who, who, who]:
            win=True;
        if transList[1]==[who, who, who]:
            win=True;
        if transList[2]==[who, who, who]:
            win=True;
        if ([transList[0][0], transList[1][1], transList[2][2]]==[who,who,who]):
            win=True;
        self.won=win;
        return win;
        
    def showBoard(self):
        for i in range(0, 3):
            for j in range (0,3):
                if j<2:
                    print (self.sym[self.board[i][j]],'| ',end="",flush=True)
                else:
                    print (self.sym[self.board[i][j]],end="",flush=True)
            print(end="\n")
        print(end="\n")
        return 0;
        
def main():
    print("Hello");
    g=xo();
    g.showBoard();
    print(g.setX(2,2));
    g.showBoard();
    print(g.won);
    
    print(g.setO(1,1));
    g.showBoard();
    print(g.won);
    
    print(g.setX(0,1));
    g.showBoard();
    print(g.won);
    
    print(g.setO(1,0));
    g.showBoard();
    print(g.won);
    
    print(g.setX(1,2));
    g.showBoard();
    print(g.won);
    
    print(g.setO(2,0));
    g.showBoard();
    print(g.won);
    
    # Playing out of turn
    print(g.setO(0,2));
    g.showBoard();
    print(g.won);
    
    # Overwriting a position
    print(g.setX(2,0));
    g.showBoard();
    print(g.won);
    
    print(g.setX(0,2));
    g.showBoard();
    print(g.won);



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Readme**

> ## XO
>
> A Python class for a game of X and O.
>
> To use the class:
>
> ```
> import xo game=xo.xo();
> ```
>
> ### `game.showBoard()`
>
> This displays:
>
> ```
>   | X | 0
> 0 | 0 | X
> 0 |   | X
> ```
>
> ### `game.setX(<posx>,<posy>)`
>
> This sets 'X' at a certain position. If successful, returns 0; else -1
>
> ### `game.setO(<posx>,<posy>)`
>
> This sets 'O' at a certain position. If successful, returns 0; else -1
>
> ### `game.won`
>
> After a move, this variable will be `True` if the last player who played has won. Else, it is `False`.

## [Updated Version](http://pastebin.com/ewkVJDW6)

## [Followup question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104946/tic-tac-toe-player-written-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: not terribly well! It's a good start (the class is a sensible idea and `if __name__ == '__main__':` is a good way to run the code), but you have made a couple of mistakes. Here are a few pointers.

---

### Style

Python has a [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which you should read and follow. A few highlights:

- Naming: classes should be `CamelCase` and function/method/attribute names should be `lowercase_with_underscores`.
- Whitespace: you should put spaces around operators, e.g. `self.board = [...]` and after commas (e.g. `self.board = [[0, 0, 0], ...]`).
- Semicolons: just don't!

---

### Documentation

It's good to have a `README`, although it's not clear what format it's in, but much better is to include [docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) for modules, classes, methods and functions, so that the script has documentation built right into it. This can also be used to generate formatted documentation (see e.g. Sphinx) and by your IDE to provide tooltips and even e.g. type hinting.

---

### DRY

Or *"don't repeat yourself"*. For example, note that `setX` and `setO` are almost exactly the same; you could refactor this to a single method which is called by the other methods as appropriate.

You could also significantly simplify `main` by using loops to reduce repetition, e.g.:

```
def main():
    print("Hello")
    g = xo()
    g.showBoard()
    now, nxt = g.setX, g.setO
    for x, y in [(2, 2), (1, 1), ...]:
        print(now(x, y))
        g.showBoard()
        print(g.won)
        now, nxt = nxt, now
```

---

### "Magic numbers"

Like `1` and `2` (for X and O) and `-1` and `-2` (not clear) are best avoided - they don't provide any useful information to the reader and make refactoring very difficult. Instead, use named "constants", e.g.:

```
PLAYER_O = 1
PLAYER_X = 2
```

Then the code becomes clearer, e.g. `self.win(PLAYER_X)` tells you what's actually happening.

---

### Naming

As well as the styling of the names, it's worth thinking about their meaning, too. It's best to avoid contractions (e.g. `self.symbols` is clearer than `self.sym`, and I've no idea what e.g. `modResX` really means). Better names means more readable code, which is a key aim of Python.

---

### Functionality

- It's conventional for a method to either change state and `return None`, or to return something but not change state - `win` returns something *and* changes state (although the return value is ignored anyway).
- Rather than `showBoard`, I would be inclined to implement a `__str__` method that returns the "friendly" representation of the board; then you can use `print(g)` rather than `g.showBoard()`. If you do retain the current functionality, note that again there's no need for a `return` value that's never used.
- `0` is the default first argument to `range`, so you can write simply e.g. `for i in range(3):`, but note that it's neater to iterate over the board itself (i.e. `for row in self.board:`, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed comments. I am fixing the code. I'll post it once it is done. About "DRY" - My thoughts were that for a small function, calling another function involves pushing context to stack and popping it back on return may cause degradation of performance. So, I chose to rewrite most of it. Is there a flaw in my reasoning? I would however like to clean up `win`.

Comment: It might be slightly less performant, but if that's a big issue you're probably using the wrong language to start with! It's unlikely to be a bottleneck, anyway.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ewkVJDW6 is an updated version.

Comment: @LordLoh. If you'd like a follow-up review, see http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1065/32391

Comment: Thank you. I have posted a follow up question - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104946/tic-tac-toe-player-written-in-python

Comment: Just to document - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8 is useful to check the script :-)